# Cloud Function to be triggered by Pub/Sub returns error Unable to resolve path to module 'firebase-functions/lib/providers/pubsub in typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have the following code

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { Message } from "firebase-functions/lib/providers/pubsub";
import { admin } from "../firebaseApp";
import { UserAccountUpdateEventScheduler } from "../core/analytics/events/account/UserAccountUpdateEventScheduler";

export const onAnalyticsEvent = functions
    .runWith({
      timeoutSeconds: 120,
      memory: "1GB",
    })
    .pubsub
    .topic("analytics-events")
    .onPublish(async (message: Message)=>{
      const eventScheduler = new UserAccountUpdateEventScheduler(admin.firestore(), message.json.userId, admin);
      await eventScheduler.send(message.json);
    });
```

But i get this error `Unable to resolve path to module 'firebase-functions/lib/providers/pubsub`

I tried to optimize it by doing this

```
import { AnalyticsEvent } from "../types/analyticsEvent.type";
import { UserAccountUpdateEventScheduler } from "../core/analytics/events/account/UserAccountUpdateEventScheduler";
import { admin } from "../firebaseApp";

import onMessagePublished = require("firebase-functions/v2/pubsub");


export const onAnalyticsEvent = onMessagePublished("analytics-events", async (event: { data: { message: { json: AnalyticsEvent; }; }; }) => {
  const eventScheduler = new UserAccountUpdateEventScheduler(admin.firestore(), event.data.message.json.userId, admin);
  await eventScheduler.send(event.data.message.json);
});
```

But i ran into another error `Cannot find module 'firebase-functions/v2/pubsub' or its corresponding type declarations.`.

I am using in my package.json

```
"firebase-admin": "11.10.0",
"firebase-functions": "4.5.0",
"firebase-tools": "11.30.0",
"@google-cloud/pubsub": "^2.19.0"
```

Any assistance is appreciated